# Python: 'int' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, list, integer, typeerror

Basically I am trying to compute the sum of the n highest values in the list a with this function.

```
def sumHighest(a, n):
    return sum(sorted(a, key = lambda numbers : (-numbers, numbers[0:n])))
```

I get this error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

I guess there's a problem with accessing - numbers[0:n] - but that's so far my only solution to access the n highest values in the list. I tried also a[0:n] instead of numbers[0:n], but that doesn't work either.

I appreciate any answer. Thanks

Comment: If they are truly just numbers, you don't need any sort key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
def sumHighest(a, n):
    return sum(sorted(a)[-n:])
```

I don't understand why you are supplying a `key` argument to `sorted`. Maybe you wanted to sort them in descending order? That would look like this if you were to do it with the `key` argument:

```
def sumHighest(a, n):
    return sum(sorted(a, key = lambda x: -x)[:n])
```

`sorted` also comes with a `reverse` argument which you should prefer when you need to simply reverse the sort order:

```
def sumHighest(a, n):
    return sum(sorted(a, reverse = True)[:n])
```

Thanks to multiple commenters for pointing this out to me :)

Comment: If they want the list in descending order, they don't even need the `key`, then can just set `reverse = True`.

Comment: Thanks much! Now I start to understand it.

Comment: @Magnus Hoff: What does -n mean in the first example and also -x in second example ?

Comment: @Praneeth It is unary negation; If `n` equals `5` then `-n` equals `-5`. (Similar for `-x`)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about a few things here. `numbers` is the parameter to the lambda expression, and as the error message says, it's an int: a `key` function is passed each element in turn to generate a key to sort against.

As others have pointed out, that has nothing to do with what you want to do: you want to just take the top n once you have sorted the list, which would not be done with a key expression.

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is small compared to size of list then you should use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) for this.

```
import heapq

def sumHighest(a, n):
    return sum(heapq.nlargest(n, a))
```